# Library/service to evaluate the complexity of an English sentence

Tags: gratis, language

I want to import a huge database of short English sentences into an educational software.
I need to categorize sentences into a few levels of "difficulty" (difficulty for a non-native to understand the sentence).

- "My name is Joe and I like ponies, dogs, cats, rabbits and mushrooms." → 0.1
- "I want to evaluate the complexity of this sentence." → 0.5
- "Beware those whose voice supersedes this very edict." → 0.9

... or any similar system of scoring.

A good algorithm would take into account:

- the difficulty of each term (Coelacanth is more difficult than goldfish because it is used less often in books, notably children/teen books. Will is more difficult than willingness because it has synonyms. etc)
  These would have to be retrieved from a pre-established database ([this might help](http://elexicon.wustl.edu/)).
- the difficulty of the grammar and conjunctions (that is more difficult than and).
- ideally the complexity of in-sentence references (sentence where several expressions refer to each other, forming a complex graph with the former at first unclear but the latter later understood... or not)
- Sentence length. This is for memorization, so a sentence twice as long might as well be considered twice as difficult.
- other parameters might be useful too.

Requirements:

- Able to process around 1,000,000 entries within a few weeks
- Free.

Bonus:

- Web service acceptable, but bonus if runnable on-premise.
- Bonus for Open Source.
- Bonus if supports other languages too.

[OGTE](http://www.er-central.com/ogte/) asks me for a sentence and a school level, then tells me whether it fits or not. I would like a tool that asks me for a sentence, and tells me what school level it fits.

Comment: Are you evaluating the complexity of the sentences based on the "difficulty" of the words used, sentence length, structure, or a combination of these factors?

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy: Added in section "A good algorithm would take into account:".

Answer (score 7):

You're actually asking two questions:

- What is a good algorithm to determine what I think is the complexity of a sentence in the english language?
- What is a program that applies this algorithm?

The first question is very hard to answer, the second one is quite easy as soon as the first one is answered.

A tool that applies various algorithms is the following. It is for free, can evaluate complete texts and you get the name of the algorithms. I suggest you read the Wikipedia pages I've linked and try to find out what suits your needs best.

### [readability-score.com](https://readability-score.com/)

#### My name is Joe and I like ponies, dogs, cats, rabbits and mushrooms.

- [Flesch-Kincaid Reading Ease](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flesch-Kincaid#Flesch_Reading_Ease): 89.5 (higher is easier)
- [Flesch-Kincaid Grade Level](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flesch-Kincaid#Flesch.E2.80.93Kincaid_Grade_Level): 4
- [Gunning-Fog Score](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gunning-Fog_Index): 5.2
- [Coleman-Liau Index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coleman-Liau_Index): 7.7
- [SMOG Index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMOG_Index): 1.8
- [Automated Readability Index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automated_Readability_Index): 3.9

#### I want to evaluate the complexity of this sentence.

- Flesch-Kincaid Reading Ease: 47.3
- Flesch-Kincaid Grade Level: 8.9
- Gunning-Fog Score: 12.5
- Coleman-Liau Index: 11.7
- SMOG Index: 8.3
- Automated Readability Index: 5.1

#### Beware those whose voice supersedes this very edict.

- Flesch-Kincaid Reading Ease: 61.2
- Flesch-Kincaid Grade Level: 6.7
- Gunning-Fog Score: 8.2
- Coleman-Liau Index: 16.6
- SMOG Index: 6
- Automated Readability Index: 8.5

Comment: *Flesch-Kincaid* and *Gunning-Fog* are really too primitive. *Coleman-Liau*, *SMOG* and *Automated Readability Index* are designed to analyze a long text/book and lose all of their value when applied to an individual sentence. I think I really need a library that uses a pre-established database of English words difficulty. Nice find though, and it is open source: https://github.com/DaveChild/Text-Statistics

Comment: OGTE seems to be using [ERF graded reader scale](http://erfoundation.org/wordpress/graded-readers/erf-graded-reader-scale) plus feedback from users.